# Trouble with referencing elements from bibliography

Tags: bibtex

I am currently writing my bachelor's thesis, and have been having some trouble with Bibtex. I created a Bibliography successfully through Mendeley - However, the way the ressources are listed are as follows:

Bibliography

book 1

book 2

...and so on.

I actually need to have them sorted alphabetically with numbers, so that when making references, I can just add the number at the end of my line (e.g. "blabla"[1] where [1] would reference to the first book in the bibliography.).

As mentioned above, I am using BibTex. Can anyone hep me, I've been struggling with this for quite a while now...

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! Just use an appropriate `\bibliographystyle{}`. If you need further help, add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I found the correct settings required!

Answer (score 1):

Correct settings:

```
\usepackage[square,numbers]{natbib}

\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
```

displays bibliography perfectly as whished!